# Why does re-initializing the webgl-context break my usage of THREE.EffectComposer?

Tags: webgl, three.js

The page I'm working on has ajax-navigation, so when the user navigates away from the part of it where I use WebGL, I stop my RequestAnimationFrame-loop and then when the user re-visits the page I re-run all WebGL setup code to recreate the scene. This works well when I use the normal renderer, but with an EffectComposer, it breaks.

Here is the code.

Initialization:

```
composerScene = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer, new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width, height, { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, format: THREE.RGBAFormat, stencilBuffer: true }));
renderModel = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);
renderModel.renderToScreen = false;
renderModel.clear = true;
filmPass = new THREE.FilmPass(filmgrainOpacity, scanlineIntensity, scanlineCount, filmpassGrayscale);
filmPass.renderToScreen = true;

composerScene.addPass(renderModel);
composerScene.addPass(filmPass);
```

Rendering:

```
composerScene.render(deltaTime);
```

When I move away from and then back to the page, the error console says:

```
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: bindBuffer: object not from this context
GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawXXX: attempt to access out of range vertices
WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.
```

And no rendering occurs. If I comment out `composerScene.addPass(filmPass);` the error no longer occurs.

Answer (score 2):

This is a dirty hack but if you do this right before you reinitialize the context it should help the EffectComposer start up again.

```
THREE.EffectComposer.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1 );
THREE.EffectComposer.quad = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 2, 2 ), null );
THREE.EffectComposer.scene = new THREE.Scene();
THREE.EffectComposer.scene.add( THREE.EffectComposer.quad );
```

If you look at the bottom of the EffectComposer code you'll see it is doing this when it loads so all you are doing is set them back to their initial state.  I have tried this in my code and I am able to reinitialize my WebGL context and use EffectComposer again without it throwing a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a bug in Three.js, I opened an [issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2951).